# Delete Button issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, onclientclick

I am using one link button in an asp.net application for delete purpose. For the confirmation i added the property of `OnClientclick="return ValidateOnDelete();"`. By Default it works as fine. But i have One condition is that When the user is not admin, the delete button will be disabled. My problem is that, if the user clicks on the delete button when it is in disabled mode, the confirmation message will come. How it can avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the button to the ValidateOnDelete() function using

```
OnClientclick="return ValidateOnDelete(this);"
```

then within the ValidateOnDelete() function do a test for the button disabled status

```
function ValidateOnDelete(button) {
   if (button.disabled) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the javascript on page load 
i.e
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof({The Wep Page Namespace}), "{Your FunctionName}", "javascript text here", true)

Or create and hidden textbox with a flag
Ie.

And then during the page load set this to 1 if its an admin users

Then refer to this box in your javascript

or add the attribute at page load
i.e
Button1.attributes.add["OnClientclick] = "return ValidateOnDelete();"

Sp